# Problem in footnote with arabtex package

Tags: footnotes, arabic, right-to-left

I have a problem if I try to typeset a footnote while using the `arabtex` package. The problem is that the number is still in left side and the text is in right side.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,arabtex,english,leqno]{arabart}
\usepackage{arabtex,utf8}\setcode{utf8}
\begin{document}
\RLfootnotes
\setarab
\begin{arabtext}
تاريخ الرياضيات في المغرب العربي \footnote{\begin{arabtext}
للدكتور ادريس لمرابط\end{arabtext}


}
\end{arabtext}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: look at the number in footnote and the text]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ibrahimmuhammed why you don't use arabi package instead of arabtex?

Answer (score 1):

You need add this command to the preamble:

```
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{% modify the style of footnotetext
  \raggedleft\noindent  #1
  \makebox[1em][r]{
    \@makefnmark
  }
}
```

Comment: This would have to be enclosed between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to prevent an error, but even then it moves the body of the footnote as well as the marker, and it affects English notes too (I assume the OP will have some, since he put `english` among the options of `arabart`). But mixing English and Arabic notes is bound to produce results that look odd in spots.